# SwiftUI conditional Text modifier .textSelection

Tags: swiftui, modifier

maybe a absolute beginner question:
In the following code is foregroundColor working but .textSelection doesn't. What is the reason?

```
Text("This is a Test")
  .foregroundColor(isSelectable ? .green : .red)
  .textSelection(isSelectable ? .enabled : .disabled)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditionally searchable Table in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75001678/conditionally-searchable-table-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot put it ternary operator, because `.enabled` and `.disabled` are of different concrete types (confirming to one protocol), so possible variant is

```
let text = "This is a Test"
Group {
    if isSelectable {
        Text(text)
          .textSelection(.enabled)
    } else {
        Text(text)
          .textSelection(.disabled)
    }
}
.foregroundColor(isSelectable ? .green : .red)
```

Note: actually Apple does not consider this feature as togglable, let's read the doc

> ```
> /// A selectability value that enables text selection by a person using your app.
> ///
> /// Enabling text selection allows people to perform actions on the text
> /// content, such as copying and sharing. Enable text selection in views
> /// where those operations are useful, such as copying unique IDs or
> /// error messages. This allows people to paste the data into
> /// emails or documents.
> ```

It's hardly imaginable that "useful informations electability" can be turned of for some reason. Just in case.

Comment: I don't understand this, I'm tryin to have something as `var textSelectability: TextSelectability = .enabled` but that doesn't work. And it doesn't make sense for me because the source code says `public func textSelection<S>(_ selectability: S) -> some View where S : TextSelectability` so as long as the argument is an implementation from `TextSelectability` it should be the correct type. And `enabled` and `disabled` both are implementations of the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I was able to have something maybe decent:

```
extension View {

    @ViewBuilder
    func textSelectable(_ isSelectable: Bool) -> some View {
        if isSelectable {
            textSelection(.enabled)
        } else {
            textSelection(.disabled)
        }
    }

}
```

You can read the @Asperi answer to figure the `protocol` implementation problem. The thing I'm trying to do here is to have this extension so it can be set programmatically in other views, like this:

```
struct ExampleView: View {

    var isTextSelectable = true

    var body: some View {
        Text(attributedString)
            .textSelectable(isTextSelectable) //here
    }

}
```

So then you can call it like this:

```
ExampleView(isTextSelectable: //true or false, make some calculation maybe)
```

This follows the advices regarding view identity from Apple derived from the source mentioned in the comments.

Comment: AnyView is highly discouraged

Comment: @loremipsum yep, I don't like it either. Can you elaborate on why it is highly discouraged?

Comment: Watch “Demystify SwiftUI” Apple talks about it there.

Comment: @loremipsum thanks, that helped me figure it out, if you could take another look? For future readers, this is the video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Comment: Definitely more in style with SwiftUI.